# Почему не меняется цвет текста в TButton?

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не меняется цвет текста в TButton: изменил в дизайн-тайме Button3.Font.Color:= clBlue; , то же пробовал в ран-тайме - не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вообще-то **Button3.Font.Color:= clBlue;** изменит только цвет надписи на кнопке. Ибо у button нет свойства цвета backgroud'a.

Cделай расширенный класс для TButton и ему  сделай новое свойство color тогда сможешь изменять цвет.

Вот материал можно взять [отсюда](http://delphiworld.narod.ru/base/colour_button.html)

Comment: Спасибо. Мне подсказали, что TButton не меняет цвет надписи. Буду использовать TBitBtn.

Comment: хм, а мне изначально показалось что нужно именно цвет кнопки изменить. Но в любом случае лучше использовать другой компонент bitbtn он расширеннее.